# LinearProgramming errors

Tags: bugs, mathematical-optimization

I have a family of equations I want to solve over the non-negative integers. One particular instance of it is this.

```
A = {{1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
{0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
{0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
{0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, 
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, 
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, 
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}}

b = {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

I'd like to solve the problem
$$
A.x = b,\quad x \in \mathbb{N}^{22}
$$
So I call up `LinearProgramming` and ask

```
LinearProgramming[ Table[0, {22}], A, {#,0}& /@ b, 
                   Table[{0,Infinity}, {22}],Table[ Integers, {22}]]
```

The purported solution is

```
c = {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

which is not, actually, a solution of the problem.

*Why does this happen?* Why doesn't *Mathematica* tell me that there is no solution?

Comment: Looks like a bug. Will investigate..

Answer (score 3):

This bug has been fixed in the recently [released](https://blog.wolfram.com/2019/04/16/version-12-launches-today-big-jump-for-wolfram-language-and-mathematica/) version 12.0

```
LinearProgramming[Table[0,{22}], A, {#, 0}& /@ b,                                                       
       Table[{0, Infinity}, {22}],Table[Integers,{22}]] // Head
```

> LinearProgramming::lpip: 
>          Warning: integer linear programming will use a machine-precision approximation of the inputs.
>
> LinearProgramming::lpsnf: No solution can be found that satisfies the
>   constraints.

```
(* LinearProgramming *)
```

Comment: That fixed earlier, at least in version 11.3.

Comment: Not exactly, it also depended on the operating system.